# Создание своего Deb based дистрибутива

Tags: linux, embedded

Нужен свой БолгенОС. В опенврт есть SDK и Image builder. Openwrt не особо десктопный, а Yocto слишком кастомный.

Нужно: сборка пакетов, необходимых для образа с некоторыми изменениями( облегчить, убрать ненужные файлы); поставка своей конфигурации по умолчанию; сборка образа со своим инитом (особенности монтирования и переразбивка диска)

Как развернуть подобные инструменты для Ubuntu или Debian? В интернете куча инструкций, но все они для ручной сборки. Желательно собирать livecd без прав рута.

Как из Убунты делают Минт?

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/buster/live-wrapper // но ключевой момент в вопросе — «без прав root-а». насколько я понимаю, это требование невыполнимо. или, как минимум, очень сложно выполнимо.

Comment: Права рута не ключевой момент. Ключевой в том чтоб это был новый дистрибутив, хоть и производный от убунту/дебиан.

Comment: кажется, понял. вам стоит для начала изложить в вопросе точный смысл, который вы вкладываете в термин «дистрибутив».

Comment: ещё и сборка пакетов добавилась! да уже только одна сборка — это отдельный и очень обширный вопрос. а у вас тут ещё никак  со сборкой пакетов не связанный вопрос про генерацию livecd. // `Как из Убунты делают Минт?` — примерно так же, как из debian-а делают ubuntu.

Comment: сборка пакетов отдельно не проблема

Comment: livecd в разделе "Желательно". первичный вопрос - создание дистрибутива

Comment: так что является проблемой? про отдельные кубики знаете: репозиторий, сборка пакетов, публикация, сборка из них установочного/livecd. что составляет трудность в собирании этих кубиков вместе?

Comment: неужели нет готовой системы сборки для дистрибутива?

Comment: отдельно трудностей нет

Comment: окей. сами не написали, что именно вкладываете, давайте я разложу по двум распространённым смыслам: 1. дистрибутив как образ загрузочного диска с набором нужных программ — автоматизировано до безобразия, вам, как я понял, знакомо. 2. дистрибутив как репозиторий с пакетами — веб-сервер либо локальный_каталог — тоже вроде вам знакомо. и наполение репозитория, как я понял, вам знакомо тоже. что тут ещё «систематизировать»?. // но вы, кажется, используете ещё какой-то смысл в словосочетании «система сборки для дистрибутива». так изложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: мне кажется должна быть система сборки которая: 1) собирает апдейты при изменении сорс пакетов 2) собирает образ диска при изменении версии релиза

Comment: @eri, по поводу пакетов — думаю, ты ищешь [buildd](https://www.debian.org/devel/buildd/)... а сборка iso'шек относительно тривиальная задача — над этим может и обычный скрипт в cron'е трудиться...

Comment: OK, то есть вопрос-то на самом деле такой: _«где мне найти исходные коды **сборочной системы** Debian (или Ubuntu)?»_ Знаю про Alt Linux, Fedora, OpenSUSE. Про Debian/Ubuntu не знаю.

Comment: исходные коды сборочной системы было б интересно посмотреть и на Альте. Ищю аналог bitbake от yocto или папки с makefile от openwrt.

Comment: https://www.altlinux.org/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E_girar-builder

Comment: https://www.altlinux.org/Mkimage-profiles